# Do not show navigation drawer when pressing drawerToggle

Tags: android

I have programmatically changed the hamburger icon to arrow in ActionBarDrawerToggle.

Obviously the navigation drawer opens up when pressing the arrow too.

How do I prevent the drawer opening up?

I already am able to make the arrow change back into hamburger icon. I just dont want the navigation drawer to open up when its in the arrow state.

Comment: what was your effort?code?researches?

Answer (score 0):

```
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener  
{
...
...
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
{
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
    {
        super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
    {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
};

mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
mDrawerToggle.syncState();

DrawerAdapter draweradapter = new DrawerAdapter(context);
lvDrawer.setAdapter(draweradapter);

...
...
}
```